# Show maintenance page when .lock file is present

Tags: symfony, nginx

guys!

I'm trying to figure out, how to show maintenance only when `.lock` file is present. The problem is, that I'm using symfony2 for my project. And I can't get it work.

I'm trying to do something like this (nginx config):

```
location / {
   if (-f $document_root/.lock) {
     rewrite ^ /maintenance last;
     break;
   }
   index app.php;
   try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/.*\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The page is shown, but all static files are redirected to /maintenance too. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Move the if block inside the rewriteapp location.

Comment: yeah, that helps, but it falls into infinite loop

Comment: You probably have to adjust the index page for /maintenance, but without logs I'm guessing.

Comment: @IlyaDoroshin what was "the another way"?

Comment: @gondo unfortunatelly, it was a long time ago.. cannot find any sources :(