# 'Website under maintenance' page in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

How can I implement a 'website under maintenance' page easely and clearly in a Symfony2 web app?

I have found something about this for Symfony 1 but nothing for Symfony2.

Thanks.

Comment: Would this be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029049/show-maintenance-page-when-lock-file-is-present I know the solution is not posted, but it can give you a direction on where to look

Comment: The solution seems to me to be the same regardless of framework: have a config file that records whether the site is under maintenance, probably checked at a low level like in a front controller somewhere, and redirect to an HTML page if it is.

Answer (score 22):

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.wenigersh.com/blog/post/maintenance-mode-for-symfony-2-applications). It is very easy and straight forward.
This was exaclty what i needed. You only have to change a parameter and then clear the prod cache and you are still able to access the application in dev or test environment.

In your parameters.yml add this:

```yaml
parameters:
    maintenance: false #turn it to true to enable maintenance
    underMaintenanceUntil: tomorrow 8 AM
```

Then you define a Service:

```yaml
services:
    acme.listener.maintenance:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\MaintenanceListener
        arguments:
            container: "@service_container"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And finally the event listener:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MaintenanceListener
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $maintenanceUntil = $this->container->hasParameter('underMaintenanceUntil') ? $this->container->getParameter('underMaintenanceUntil') : false;
        $maintenance = $this->container->hasParameter('maintenance') ? $this->container->getParameter('maintenance') : false;

        $debug = in_array($this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment(), array('test', 'dev'));

        if ($maintenance && !$debug) {
            $engine = $this->container->get('templating');
            $content = $engine->render('::maintenance.html.twig', array('maintenanceUntil'=>$maintenanceUntil));
            $event->setResponse(new Response($content, 503));
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }

    }
}
```

Then you just have to add the template file referenced in `$content = $engine->render('::maintenance.html.twig', array('maintenanceUntil'=>$maintenanceUntil));` and your fine. Use `{{ maintenanceUntil }}` to display the message defined in parameters.yml.

Comment: I added this to my symfony 2.7 project but it only works correctly when I clear the prod cache after changing the maintenance parameter in the yml. It has no effect, when I don't clear the cache. Is there a way to avoid this additional step?

Comment: Short answer, no. Parameters are cached too I guess.

Comment: you're right. I tested it and the config files are cached. But maybe there's a comfortable solution to create a command which changes the yml and then cleares the cache. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: The config files as well as the parameters are always cached. After all you `import` the `parameters.yml` file in your `config.yml` so that's why it's cached as well. Anyway, if you're performing some action in a controller (i.e. you have a checkbox which sets the `maintenance` parameter) you could use something like this in your controller: https://gist.github.com/steve-todorov/d92d595504c719500acd.